# Can't get backbone to render anything

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to pick up a bit of backbone.js, but failing at the first hurdle. It just won't render anything. I've tried many different 'getting started' articles, but still nothing. No errors, just nothing. I've reduced it down to something which I think should work based on what I've read, but now I'm completely unsure about anything. Please help...

Edit: Updated with JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zsLjawy0/

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/template" id="test">
            test
        </script>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.render();
            console.log('this does nothing');
        },
        render: function() {
            var template = _.template( $("#test").html(), {} );
            this.$el.html( template );

            return this; // Also does nothing
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: What is the error in console?

Comment: Add your code to fiddle

Comment: Updated post with jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

First of all, as indicated Voice, at some point you need to create an instance of your view otherwise there is no way your initialze thne render functions occur. ==> MyView = new TestView();

Second point you need to define a template and an #el so you can render properly.

```
TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: #test,
    template: _.template(LoadAtemplateWithREQUIREJS_it_would_be_wise),

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
        console.log('this does nothing');
    },
    render: function() {
        var template = 
        this.$el.html( this.template(someParams_amodelforinstance);

        return this; // Also does nothing
    }
});
```

Last point, don't use a script as your div target, use a div.
This :

```
<div id="test"> </div>
```

I let you find out why.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks, I finally found a simpler tutorial and figured it out myself https://cdnjs.com/libraries/backbone.js/tutorials/what-is-a-view/

Answer (score 0):

As I see, your app just defines TestView but does not create an instance of it and does not render it. You should create an instance of TestView, render it and add rendered content to the document.